# setting `tuneLength` in `caret::rfe()`

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection, caret, rfe

if I set `tuneLength` in `caret::rfe()`, does the tuning apply to both line 2.9 and 2.17 in the following from [caret's site](https://topepo.github.io/caret/recursive-feature-elimination.html#backwards-selection)? if 2.9 only, what are the hyper-parameters used in 2.17?

[image]

Also, is the `tuneLength` passed to `rfeControl$functions$fit`? and does `rfeControl$functions$fit` actually run `train`?